# Theorem between subharmonic function and integrablity

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem I am now reading is Theorem 1.6.9 in Hörmander's textbook

> **Theorem 1.6.9** Let $u$ be subharmonic in the open set $\Omega$ and not $-\infty$ identically in any component of $\Omega$. Then $u$ is
> integrable on all compact subsets of $\Omega$ (we write $u \in
>  L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$), which implies $u < -\infty$ almost everywhere.

To begin with, to check the integrablity, author uses the equivalence relation of subarmonic function. : *If $\Omega_{\delta}: \left \{ z : d(z, \mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega) > \delta \right \}$ ,then we have $u(z) 2 \pi \int d\mu(r) \le  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int u(z+re^{i\theta}) d\theta d\mu(r)$ for all $z \in \Omega_{\delta}$, for every positive measure $d\mu$ on the interval $[0,\delta]$.*.....(♣)

**[Question (A): The question about integrablity]**
The author picks $z \in \Omega$, $u(z)>-\infty$, $D$ is a closed disk with center at $z$ contained in $\Omega$. (Since the assumption of the statement of (♣), I think that the closed disk $D$ is contained in $\Omega$). Again, since $u$ is subharmonic, inequality on (♣) holds. The author says since $u$ is bounded in $D$ that is integrable over $D$. However, **I do not accurately understand the between inequality of (♣) and integrability**. From (♣), clearly, $u(z)$ is bounded when dividing each term as $\int d \mu(r)$. However, boundness does not imply integrability in general.

**[Question (B): The question about almost everywhere.]**
The author also refers that $ u \in L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$ implies $u>-\infty$ *almost everywhere*. In other words, a subharmonic function $u$ cannot have the value $-\infty$ except the measure zero set. Thus, I expect that if one collects all points $z$ which yield $u(z)=-\infty$, then its measure would be zero.  The following is the proof on the textbook :

> Let $E$ be a set all of $z$ such that $u$ is integrable over a
> neighborhood of $z$. Then it follows that $u=-\infty$ in a
> neighborhood of every point in $\Omega \setminus E$. Hence both $E$
> and $\Omega \setminus E$ are open so that $\Omega \setminus E$ is a
> union of components of $\Omega$, all of which must be empty by
> hypothesis since $u=-\infty$ in $\Omega \setminus E$.

In my thought, clearly, $~\Omega \setminus E$ corresponds to the collection of points $z$ which yields $u(z)=-\infty$. **However, I cannot deduce my expectation from the above proof**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that $u$ is locally Lebesgue-integrable, which means for any compact $K \Subset \Omega$,
$$\int_K |u|(x)\, dx = \sup \Big\{ \int_K s(x)\, dx \mid s \mbox{ simple },\ s \leqslant |u| \mbox{ on } K \Big\} < \infty.$$
If $u$ is only measurable, you cannot always attribute a value (even infinite) to $\int_K u(x)\, dx$. But if $u$ is upper semi-continuous (*usc*) as any subharmonic functions are by definition, you can define $\int_K u(x)\, dx$ *a priori*. Set
$$ \int_K u(x)\, \mathbf{dx} = \inf \Big\{ \int_K g(x)\, dx \mid g \in \mathcal{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^n),\ u \leqslant g \mbox{ on } K\Big\} \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}.$$
I wrote $\mathbf{dx}$ in bold font in order to emphasize the difference with the Lebesgue integral. This definition gives a reasonable notion of integral for *usc* functions, see Chapter 13 of [Postmodern analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05306-5). Notice Hörmander used this definition in order to prove (♣). Otherwise, his theorem 1.6.3 (ii) didn't make any sense since he proved that $u$ is locally integrable latter.

> If $u$ is *usc* on $\Omega$ and $K \Subset \Omega$ then $u$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $K$ if and only if $\int_K u(x)\, \mathbf{dx} > -\infty$.

**Proof:** Indeed, since $u$ is *usc*, for any $z \in K$ there exists a neighbourhood $B$ around $z$ on which $u$ is bounded **from above** by a constant, which can be assumed to be zero. Thus, if $u$ is not Lebesgue-integrable on $B$, we have $\int_B u(x)\, dx = -\infty$. According to Theorem 12.11 of [Postmodern analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05306-5), there exists a monotonically decreasing sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions with compact support converging to $u$ on $\Omega$. Replacing $f_n$ by $\max \{f_n , 0\}$, we can assume without loss of generality that $f_n \leqslant 0$ on $B$. Thus by the monotone convergence theorem, we have
$$ \int_K u(x)\, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_K f_n(x)\, dx = -\infty.$$
Since $\{f_n\}$ is decreasing sequence converging to $u$, we have $u \leqslant f_n$ on $K$. Thus $\int_K u(x)\, \mathbf{dx} = -\infty$.

Now it is clear that $u$ is locally Lebesgue-integrable if you assume that $u$ is not $-\infty$ identically on some connected components of $\Omega$.

For your second question, the set $\Omega \backslash E$ is not the polar set of $u$. Indeed $\Omega \backslash E$ is open but $P = \{ u = -\infty \}$ is not always open (e.g. $u = \log |z|$). If the measure of $P$ is not zero then by regularity of the Lebesgue measure, you can find a compact $K \subset P$ of positive measure. Thus
$$ \int_K u \geqslant - \int_K \infty = -\infty,$$
which is a contradiction with the local integrability of $u$.

**Edit:** on reflexion, there is a simpler manner to define the integral of a *usc* function on compact. Since a *usc* function is bounded from above on any compact $K$, you can set
$$ \int_K u(x)\, dx = \int_K (u(x)-M)\, dx + M \cdot \int_K dx,$$
where $M$ is the maximum of $u$ on $K$. The integral makes sense since $u-M$ is of constant sign and the second term of the right-hand side is finite.

Comment: Is the difference measure you referred $\mathbf{dx}$  is a "Rieze measure"? (I just google the following keyword: subharmonic, measure)

Comment: Not at all. The Riesz measure is a generalization of the Laplacian operator to non-smooth subharmonic functions. If $u$ is of class $C^2$, it is just $(\Delta u)\, d\lambda$ where $\Delta u$ is the classical Laplacian operator and $d\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. I don't know if the integral of usc functions can be expressed as a Lebesgue integral for some appropriate measure but it doesn't matter in our situation since this integral agrees with the Lebesgue one as soon as the function is Lebesgue-integrable.